# Show that $2\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})=\cos \theta$ iff $\theta = (4n+2)\pi \pm 2\phi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Q:

> Show that $2\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})=\cos \theta$ if and only if
> $\theta=(4n+2)\pi\pm 2\phi$ where $\phi$ is defined by $\cos(\phi)= \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt 3-1)\;$, $0\le \phi\le \frac{1}{2}\pi$, and $n$
> is any integer

Workings

$2\cos(\frac{\theta}{2}) = \cos(\theta) \iff 2\cos(\frac{\theta}{2}) = \cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2}) - \sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2}) \iff 2\cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2})-2\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})-1=0$

So we have, $$ \cos(\frac{\theta}{2}) = \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

but, $\cos(\frac{\theta}{2}) \not = \frac{1}{2} +\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ > 1

So $\cos(\frac{\theta}{2}) = \frac{1}{2} -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$\therefore \frac{\theta}{2} = \pm \cos^{-1}(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2})+2\pi n$

$\therefore \theta = \pm 2\cos^{-1}(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2})+4\pi n$

I notice that the form is similar to what the question wants us to show. But it's not quite the same. Any idea where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Note that $\cos^{-1}(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2})=\pi-\phi$.

Comment: @mathlove Alright. So from here $\theta = \pm 2(\pi-\phi) + 4\pi n$, how do we get into the form which they require? $\theta = \pi(4n\pm 2) \pm 2\phi$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have correctly got
$$ \theta = \pm 2\cos^{-1}\bigg(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2}\bigg)+4\pi n$$

Now, note that
$$\cos^{-1}\bigg(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2}\bigg)=\pi-\phi$$
So, one finally has
$$ \theta = \pm 2(\pi-\phi)+4\pi n,$$
i.e.
$$\theta=(4n+2)\pi-2\phi,\ (4n-2)\pi+2\phi$$
where the latter can be written as
$$\theta=(4m+2)\pi+2\phi$$
where $m=n-1$.

Therefore, one can write
$$\theta=(4n+2)\pi\pm 2\phi$$